# sending keyboard interrupt programmatically

Tags: python, windows

An application that asks for a keyboard interrupt. How can I send for a keyboard interrupt programmatically? I need it for automation.
Like `<C-c>` or `<C-x>`

```py
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Do you mean "interrupt" in the sense of Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break?

Comment: Does this help? http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/599370-windows-sending-ctrl-c-event-console-application

Answer (score 4):

Code running in a separate thread can cause a `KeyboardInterrupt` to be generated in the main thread by calling `thread.interrupt_main()`.
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention automation I assume you want a SendKeys for Python. Try this: http://rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to solve this problem is to use the following code pattern. I used it to programmatically start a tensorboard server and shut it down by sending a CTRL-C when the object it belongs to is deleted. Generally speaking, this should work for any example that provokes a subprocess that is supposed to be send a KeyBoardInterrupt:

1. Import signal and subprocess

   ```
   import signal
   import subprocess
   ```
2. Create the subprocess using subprocess.Popen. Important: set the **creationflags** parameter to **subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP**. This is necessary to later be able to send the KeyboardInterrupt event.

   ```
   command= <enter your command that is supposed to be run in different process as a string> 
   process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
   ```
3. Wherever you want to send the keyboardInterrupt, do the following:

   ```
   process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
   ```

That is it! Please see the [the official subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?msclkid=b8b42ebca9e611ecb63e6a8818369bd6) for insights on why the creationflags parameter of popen has to be set that way.

---

This is how the code looks for my example in a less generic way:

```
import signal
import subprocess
import time

class ExperimentTracker():
   
     def __init__(self):
         self.tensorboard_process=None

     def __del__(self):
         #shutdown tensorboard server and terminate process
         self.tensorboard_process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
         time.sleep(0.2)
         self.tensorboard_process.kill()

     def launch_tensorboard(self):
         #launch tensorboard
         bashCommand= "tensorboard --logdir runs" 
         self.tensorboard_process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP) 
         time.sleep(2) #sleep for 2 seconds to give tensorboard time to be launched
```

Answer (score 0):

If say you want to run a program via shell `./program`. In Linux what you could do is:

```sh
# Made a function to handle more complex programs which require multiple inputs.
run(){
    ./program
}

# Making a child process that will run the program while you stop it later.
run & 
childPid=($!)
# Process id of the program which you want to interrupt (via `run`).

# Time after which you want to interrupt
sleep 5

# Actual command to send the interrupt
kill -SIGINT $childPid
```

Let me know if it works in windows as well.